# Can i formulate any curve with parametric equation?

Tags: parametric

Can i formulate any curve with parametric equation ? if not, so what kind of curves can be explained with parametric equations ?! Thanks in advance

Comment: Please define *parametric equation*.

Comment: What definition are you taking for "curve"? The usual understanding is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ into your space, so then the answer is trivially "yes".

Comment: @MichaelHoppe [Parametric equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation)

Comment: When you draw a curve with a pencil, you are already giving the coordinates over a parameter: time.

Comment: @Neal plane curve indeed

Comment: @farzad: Are you focusing on a certain plane curve?

Comment: @B.S.: No,Parabola,Circle,Helix are some example of 2D or 3D curves that i  have interest.

Comment: @B.S. age soal tabdil beshe be "aya mishe har khati o ru safe 2d be ye taabe tabdil kard ?" ke khob javab malume "na" chon momkene monhani be ezaye yek X 2ta Y dashte bashe , vali aya baraye parametric ham intore ?intor nistesh chon circle taabe nis vali ba parametric namayesh esh mishe dad

Comment: @farzad: Hamin khube. Haminu benewis. amma jawabe akharesho ke hadse khodete ziyad ru nakon. Alliye. Ishalla jawab migiri. :-)